# Column values as stored procedure input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following code when inputting parameters for a SP:

```
USE [MDAmanager]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spCougarExport]
        @PropertyCodeString = NULL,
        @Date = NULL,
        @InferDate = NULL,
        @TransactionCodeString = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

For the `@PropertyCodeString` I would like to pass the values from a seperate table with all the property codes.

Below is an example of the property codes

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is have the SP always return all properties and not require updating the property codes when a new property is added.

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to amend your SP then you can utilise a user defined table type e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PropertyCode_UDT] AS TABLE
(   [PropertyCode] [bigint] NOT NULL
)
GO

DECLARE @PCTab [dbo].[PropertyCode_UDT]
;

INSERT INTO @PCTab
(   [PropertyCode]
)
SELECT PC.[PropertyCode]
FROM [dbo].[PropertyCode] PC
;

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spCougarExport]
    @PropertyCode  = @PCTab,
    @Date = NULL,
    @InferDate = NULL,
    @TransactionCodeString = NULL
;
```

Your Sp will need to be amended to accept the correct type for @PropertyCode and you can just join your query within the SP on this table to get all the Property Codes

Eg

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCougarExport]
    @Date [date]
,   @InferDate [date]
,   @TransactionCodeString [nvarchar] (MAX)
,   @PropertyCode PropertyCode_UDT READONLY
AS BEGIN;
.......
SELECT ...
FROM @PropertyCode atPC
```

Comment: Thanks. So is there a comparatively easy way without amending the SP? Or this the easier route? I have never made an SP so I'll try and amend as above.

Comment: I believe this is the only way to pass a list of values to an SP.

Comment: PS if you're happy with this answer please mark it as so. Thanks